# How do I redirect users to an error 404 page if they enter a trailing "/" (or anything after a "/"), after the page name?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On an Apache/Linux Server, how  do I redirect users to an error 404 page if they enter a trailing "/" (or anything after a "/") after the page name?

For example, this URL should direct to an error page:

```
http://www.example.com/contactus.php/someextrastuffhere
```

Whereas, this URL should not:

```
http://www.example.com/contactus.php?name=john+smith&email=johnsmith@webpage.com
```

However, the latter URL breaks my site.

Can this be solved with a simple `.htaccess` directive?

Comment: I guess you have some sort of filter set up for that. Is it php, .htaccess.. ? also, include it in the description of your problem so we can check it out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have this rule as your very first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^.+?\.(php|html?)/ - [L,R=404,NC]
```

This will send any `/file.php/foo` request to 404 whereas `http://www.example.com/contactus.php?name=john+smith&email=johnsmith@webpage.com` won't be impacted.

Comment: Absolutely spot on @arco444, I mistyped it. Thanks!

Comment: It looks as though that would only work for .php pages, excluding .html, .htm. Am I right? How could it be modified to also include the latter.